# Arcustangent function of the Apollo Computer, atan() or atan2()?

Tags: apollo-program, history, flight-computer

What type of the arcustangent function was used, the one with single argument only or the famous atan2(y, x) or arctan2(y, x) with two arguments x and y? What kind of aproximation was used?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30952/how-did-the-apollo-computers-evaluate-transcendental-functions-like-sine-arctan/30955#30955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Two arguments, but not exactly like *atan2*()

The first thing you should understand is that although `ARCTAN` is called in 3 places in the Apollo code, in every case it is used for converting rectilinear coordinates (x, y, z) into spherical coordinates (r, latitude, longitude).

I will describe how `ARCTAN` is used in the `LAT-LONG` subroutine, in file [LATITUDE_ LONGITUDE_ SUBROUTINES.agc](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11/blob/27e2acf88a6345e2b1064c8b006a154363937050/Comanche055/LATITUDE_LONGITUDE_SUBROUTINES.agc#L77-L89), although the use is similar in the other callers.  The first step is to compute gamma = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (lines 77-82).  We then divide x and y each by gamma; x/gamma is stored in global variable `COSTH` and y/gamma is stored in global variable `SINTH` (lines 83-87).  We are then ready to call the `ARCTAN` subroutine (line 88).  After it returns, the result is stored in global variable `LAT` (line 89).  A similar set of calculations determines the longitude.

```
77:     DLOAD   DSQ
78:     ALPHAV
79:     PDDL    DSQ
80:     ALPHAV +2
81:# Page 1237
82:     DAD SQRT
83:     DMP SL1R
84:     GAMRP
85:     STODL   COSTH       # COS(LAT) B-1
86:     ALPHAV +4
87:     STCALL  SINTH       # SIN(LAT) B-1
88:     ARCTAN
89:     STODL   LAT     # LAT B0
```

Like *atan2*(), `ARCTAN` takes two arguments.  However, unlike *atan2*(), the arguments must already be pre-divided.  In other words, they must be in the range of -1 to +1, and their squares must add to 1.   The arguments are taken from the global variables `COSTH` and `SINTH`.  As the names suggest and because of the pre-division, these arguments are the cosine and sine of the angle we are looking for.  The bulk of the subroutine checks the +/- sign of the arguments, adjusting the result for the appropriate quadrant.  The main calculation is done by calling `ASIN` with argument `SINTH` (line 219).

```
196:        # Page 1240
197:        # ARCTAN SUBROUTINE
198:        #
199:        # CALLING SEQUENCE
200:        #   SIN THETA IN SINTH B-1
201:        #   COS THETA IN COSTH B-1
202:        #   CALL ARCTAN
203:        #
204:        # OUTPUT
205:        #   ARCTAN THETA IN MPAC AND THETA B-0 IN RANGE -1/2 TO +1/2
206:        
207:        ARCTAN      BOV
208:                    CLROVFLW
209:        CLROVFLW    DLOAD   DSQ
210:                    SINTH
211:                PDDL    DSQ
212:                    COSTH
213:                DAD
214:                BZE SQRT
215:                    ARCTANXX    # ATAN=0/0.  SET THETA=0
216:                BDDV    BOV
217:                    SINTH
218:                    ATAN=90
219:                SR1 ASIN
220:                STORE   THETA
221:                PDDL    BMN
222:                    COSTH
223:                    NEGCOS
224:                DLOAD   RVQ
225:        NEGCOS      DLOAD   DCOMP
226:                BPL DAD
227:                    NEGOUT
228:                    DP1/2
229:        ARCTANXX    STORE   THETA
230:                RVQ
231:        
232:        NEGOUT      DSU GOTO
233:                    DP1/2
234:                    ARCTANXX
235:        ATAN=90     DLOAD   SIGN
236:                    LODP1/4
237:                    SINTH
238:                STORE   THETA
239:                RVQ
```

`ASIN` is a macro for the `ARCSIN` subroutine in file [INTERPRETER.agc](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11/blob/27e2acf88a6345e2b1064c8b006a154363937050/Comanche055/INTERPRETER.agc).  In turn, it is computed from the arccosine, using the relation ARCSIN(X) = PI/2 - ARCCOS(X).  (Lines 2704-2705.  Yeah, even though we already have the cosine stored in `COSTH`.)  `ARCCOS` is calculated using the "Hastings approximation" and a 7th degree polynomial.

The result of each of the inverse trig subroutines are angles in the range of -1/2 to +1/2.  To convert to radians, you must multiply by $\pi$ .

So, there are two arguments, but they must be pre-divided, and the result must be multiplied by $\pi$ .

Comment: Could you explain what is done in line 214? The case arctan = 0 for x = 0 and y = 0?

Comment: @uwe BZE is branch when zero, if true it will run ARCTANXX (after that I am lost). Not sure what RVQ does, return value quit maybe?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: RVQ is Return via QPRET. Returns to the location specified in the QPRET register. This is the normal way to return from a subroutine, although if the QPRET register had previously been saved to a memory location, then GOTO can be used instead. BZE seems to use the previously computed value gamma = sqrt(x^2+y^2) to find out if both x and y are zero.

Comment: @DrSheldon Do you want to take a stab at https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31196/195 ?

Comment: RVQ = return via the Q register.  Unconditional jumps store the old program counter in the Q register.  This allows the same instruction to be used as a subroutine call.  To return, you just jump back to the address that was in the Q register.

Comment: Line 214 is indeed a special case for x = 0 and y = 0.  We check such condition by examining if gamma ends up being zero.  It is treated as a special case that always returns an angle of zero.  What is the longitude at +90 degrees latitude?  It should be undefined -- but we must return some number -- so we return zero.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I've been working on it and hope to have an answer later today!

Comment: But the value of arctan2(+0,+0) or arctan(0) is well defined and equal to +0. atan2(+0, −0) = +π is a different thing.

Comment: @Uwe: atan2(+0, +0) might be well defined, but this is not the atan2 function!  Think of the planar polar coordinates for x = 0, y = 0.  What is the angle?  Trigonometrically, it's undefined.  But they have to make this subroutine return some number, so they decided to make this case return an angle of zero.

Answer (score -5):

Here you can see source code of the Apollo 11 Guidance computer.

https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11/blob/27e2acf88a6345e2b1064c8b006a154363937050/Comanche055/LATITUDE_LONGITUDE_SUBROUTINES.agc

Inside, see Subroutine for ARCTAN.

Answers your question?

Comment: That's a link's only answer, and only understandable for people who can read assembly. The question asks which mathematical approach was used, not so much the source code.

Comment: @Hobbes There are different assembly languages, at least one per type of processor.  I'm not sure what language the code is using, but it's not one I'm familiar with, and I've been around for a while.  I can't tell what algorithm the code is using.

Comment: @DavidThornley see answers to [How did the Apollo computers evaluate transcendental functions like sine, arctangent, log?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30952/12102) for more on the particular flavor

Comment: RobinC welcome to Stack Exchange! It's a big different than other sites you may have used. You can get a feeling for what kinds of answers are well-received by looking around at other answers and have a look at [How to Answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as well. The four-quadrant correct atan2 is really important in engineering applications and so it is certainly implemented *somehow* If ARCTAN doesn't do that (you have not yet said if it does or doesn't) then this will be handled by whatever *calls ARCTAN* and so your answer should expand on that.

Comment: Right now it's called a "link-only" answer and this is strongly discouraged (and down-voted) because links break and then the answer becomes useless and the question becomes unanswered again. The idea is to write answers that are helpful to future readers as well as the OP.

Comment: The lines 199 to 202 looks like arctan(theta) is calculated from sin(theta) and cos(theta) but is there a trigonometric equation for that? At least for -0.5 < theta < 0.5?