# Lunar ascent module: Guidance Law

Tags: guidance, apollo-program

I was wondering if there was an optimal law for the thrust (magnitude and direction) during the lunar ascent. I have read many things about this topic in this forum but I still have some doubts. It should be a linear steering law, but what are the values ​​of the constants? What is the actual guidance law used in Apollo 11 for? There is no non-linear parameterization fot the thrust angle that also changes according to the direction of the velocity of LM?

Comment: NASA's technical archive: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/

Comment: It's basically a gravity turn after the initial climb to avoid terrain. I don't believe the ascent engine was throttleable.

Comment: @JCRM Correct, the ascent engine didn't throttle.

Comment: Related: [How does the Apollo LM ascent guidance program work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31196/195)

Comment: Is it possible to talk directly with an user? In particular I would have some questions for @RussellBorogove because I just read his analysis of this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I've created a chat room for the topic; be aware that it is public. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/90521/lm-ascent?tab=general

Comment: Thanks @RussellBorogove. Unfortunately I can't talk in that chat because apparently I don't have enough "reputation" points.